# GGears under Linux Chrome/Chromium

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, google-chrome, google-gears

i find out, that in Karmic Koala is already package realy containing GGears, but it somehow seems it's not supposed for Chrome/Chromium, but only for Firefox.

**Is there some way to enable gears under Chrome/Chromium since i installed the gears package?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no plan to support Gears under Chrome/Chromium, [the devs have mentioned](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17443) that they will use HTML5 local storage capabilities instead of Gears.

> No current plan to implement this.
>
> Gears overlaps with a lot of HTML5
>   (since many HTML5 features are derived
>   from Gears).   Current plan is to skip
>   Gears and go directly to HTML5
>   implementations within Chrome.
>
> (Getting Gears as is to work in Linux
>   Chrome sounds like a lot of effort,
>   for various  reasons I don't fully
>   understand.  Depending on how quickly
>   the HTML5 stuff happens,  we may
>   revisit this decision.)